# How to use non-laravel package at Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, package, integration-testing, checkout

I use Laravel 5.1 and we use Stripe but now I need to change to checkout.com
Checkout.com has one php library: https://github.com/checkout/checkout-php-library

I want to implement into my app. FIrst I run :

```
composer require checkout/checkout-php-api
```

so I install the library and library is inside `vendor/checkout` folder

I use OrderController and I create public function checkout:

```
require_once 'vendor\checkout\checkout-php-library\autoload.php';

use com\checkout;

class OrdersController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
public function payment() {

  return view('front.checkout');

}

public function checkout(Request $request) {

  $data = $request->all();


$apiClient = new ApiClient('sk_test_aaaaaa-5116-999-9270-999999999');
// create a charge serive
$charge = $apiClient->chargeService();

try {
    /**  @var ResponseModels\Charge  $ChargeRespons **/
    $ChargeResponse = $charge->verifyCharge($data['cko-card-token']);

} catch (com\checkout\helpers\ApiHttpClientCustomException $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception Message: ',  $e->getErrorMessage(), "\n";
    echo 'Caught exception Error Code: ',  $e->getErrorCode(), "\n";
    echo 'Caught exception Event id: ',  $e->getEventId(), "\n";
}



}
```

Now when I make POST request I get:

> FatalErrorException in OrdersController.php line 26: main(): Failed
>   opening required 'vendor\checkout\checkout-php-library\autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

**How to integrate this library into my Laravel project?**

update:
at frontend I have this code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.checkout.com/js/frames.js"></script>
  <form id="payment-form" method="POST" action="{{url()}}/checkout">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div class="frames-container">
      <!-- form will be added here -->
    </div>
    <!-- add submit button -->
    <button id="pay-now-button" type="submit" disabled>Pay now</button>
  </form>

    <script>
    var paymentForm = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var payNowButton = document.getElementById('pay-now-button');

    Frames.init({
      publicKey: 'pk_test_aaaaaaaaa-000-41d9-9999-999999999',
      containerSelector: '.frames-container',
      customerName: 'John Smith',
      billingDetails: {
        addressLine1: '623 Slade Street',
        addressLine2: 'Apartment 8',
        postcode: '31313',
        email: 'asd@asd.asd',
        country: 'US',
        city: 'Hinesville',
        phone: { number: '9125084652' }
      },
      cardValidationChanged: function () {
        // if all fields contain valid information, the Pay now
        // button will be enabled and the form can be submitted
        payNowButton.disabled = !Frames.isCardValid();
      },
      cardSubmitted: function () {
        payNowButton.disabled = true;
        // display loader
      }
    });
    paymentForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Frames.submitCard()
        .then(function (data) {
          Frames.addCardToken(paymentForm, data.cardToken);
          paymentForm.submit();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          // catch the error
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I run composer dump-autoload and I got this folder structure: https://www.screencast.com/t/dMz7oubLLn

Comment: go to root of package and run composer install

Comment: I run but there is no composer.json file

Comment: there is a composer.json file on repo tho

Comment: Sorry yes, here is what I got: https://www.screencast.com/t/REqxid6Fku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include the package using `include_once`.

1. Because it will get super messy super fast when you need to use it in other parts of your application.
2. Placing the API secret key in your source code is a bad idea. That key might linger in your Git or turn to be in places you don't want it to be found. Also, suppose your key changed, you will have to go and fish all the parts you used the the key in the source code to replace it.

---

Read about Service Providers https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers in which you can create a 'wrapper' for the `checkout/checkout-php-api` and you'll be able to use it throughout your Laravel application as:

```
<?php

use AleksPer\Checkout\CheckoutAPI;

public function checkout(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->all();


  /**
   * There's no need to inject the API key here,
   * Assuming it is injected when the library is bootstrapped.
   * 
   */
   $apiClient = new CheckoutAPI();
   $charge = $apiClient->chargeService();
}
```

Or if registered/bootstrapped `checkout-php-api` as a singleton, you can reference it throughout your application as `app('checkoutApi');` with having your created Service Provider injecting the required parameters, which brings me to my next point:

Have your keys be placed in the project's `.env` e.g.

`CHECKOUT_SECRET_KEY=sk_***************`

and of course, to load that env variable in your service provider: `env('CHECKOUT_SECRET_KEY')`.

---

Do some Googling about:

- 'creating composer packages'
- 'creating laravel packages'
- 'create api wrapper laravel'

You'll find plenty of answers.

Comment: Can you please pst here how to create Laravel provider step by step ?

Comment: @AleksPer You will be able to easily do it once you finish at least 1 simple 'create a laravel package' tutorial, then use Laravel's documentation about Service Providers. I'll try to write the steps but don't wait into it! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Package autoloader not being included.

After adding the library to your project, include the file autoload.php found in root of the library.

```
include 'checkout-php-api/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Now when I try to get view I got: ErrorException in OrdersController.php line 27:
include(checkout-php-api/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: in the root of library not controller

Comment: but in which file? Where I need to add this line?

Comment: delete package then composer update composer clearcache  and then  composer require checkout/checkout-php-api

Comment: Ok, I do what you tell me... what next?